# How many ways are there to place $n$ resistors in a circuit?

Tags: combinatorics

You have $n$ resistors (unnumbered and with same value). How many ways are there to place all these $n$ resistors in a circuit?

Connections in series and parallel shall be considered.

F.e. $n=1 \to 1$ possibility

$n=2 \to 2$ possibilities

$n=3 \to 6$ possibilities

Comment: There are $n!$ possibilities to place these in a circuit.

Comment: @amWhy: by using parenthesis for representing parallel circuits, shouldn't the answer be given by a Catalan number?

Comment: you are likely correct, @Jack.  It just reveals my awful understanding of various connections in circuits!

Comment: For $n=2$ ... $P(1,1)$ & $S(1,1)$. For $n=3$ I can only find $4$ ways to do it (I could persaude myself to double count one of them ... but I would not be happy). $P(1,1,1)$,$P(1,S(1,1))$,$S(1,P(1,1))$, $S(1,1,1)$ ... can someone correct me ? :-(

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I agree.

Comment: @amWhy: actually we were both wrong - https://oeis.org/A048211

Comment: One assumes, to give a different total resistance, e.g S(1, P(1, 1)) = S(P(1, 1), 1)) ?

Comment: @TomCollinge  Jack's Reference looks right to me. & I guess there is no simple recurrence relation. $n=25$ has only recently been calculated to be $2 \frac{1}{2}$ billion.